# Jquery datepicker not reflecting back to a hidden input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following jquery datapicker script and my objective is to convert the user selection to timestamp so that it can be later saved to a database. but right now im trying to get the results to display in the hidden file which isn't working.
any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){                
                 $("#date").datepicker({
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    minDate: '0M',
                    maxDate: '+90D',    
                    dateFormat: "d-MM-yy",  
                   });
                    var dateString = $('#date').val();
                    var timestamp = Date.parse(dateString).getTime()/1000; 
                    $('#hidden1').val( timestamp );                 
           });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div> 
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
            <p> Enter expire date: <br />
            <input type="text" name="date" id="date"/></p>  
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" id="hidden1"  value=""/>            
            <button type="submit" name="btn_test" >Test Button</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears form your code that you are using the Jquery datepicker control:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

This currently will only execute once.

So you need to bind to a triggering event such as the change event as such:

```
   $("#date").change(function(){
        var dateString = $('#date').val();
        var timestamp = Date.parse(dateString).getTime()/1000; 
        $('#hidden1').val( timestamp ); 
   });
```

You also need to access the datepicker value:

```
 var dateString = $( "#date" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
```

rather than:

```
 var dateString = $('#date').val();
```

resulting in:

```
 $("#date").datepicker({
     showButtonPanel: true,
     minDate: '0M',
     maxDate: '+90D',    
     dateFormat: "d-MM-yy"  
 }).change(function(){
     var dateString = $( "#date" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
     if(dateString != null){
         var timestamp = dateString.getTime()/1000; 
         $('#hidden1').val( timestamp ); 
     }
 });
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eQqVg/6/

Comment: Hello, I tried your suggestion and the code itself works but its not passing the variable timestamp to #hidden1 for some reason.. the date input  controller works but not the hidden1 input controller...

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the change event as the onblur event was firing inconsistantly. I've also added null protection for no date present. Although I've not had chance to try it with Date.parse.

Comment: I've checked and Jquery date pickers return a native Jquery date object, as such this shouldn't need parsing. Updated my answer to show this.